# How to lint for a harry robert's BEM convention with stylelint?

Tags: sass, postcss, bem, stylelint

[PostCSS BEM Linter](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter) plugin needs [component definition](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter#defining-a-component-and-utilities) for each block which is a time consuming thing to do in a legacy project.

Is there a way to use [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) to check for the classes pattern and show error in all stylesheets (.scss in my case) of the project without needing component definition in each file/block?

https://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/

```
.block {}
.block__element {}
.block--modifier {}
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/davidtheclark/stylelint-selector-bem-pattern?

Answer (score 3):

I have a working example following on from @jeddy3 answer.
This is a copy of my `stylelint.config.js`

We override the `bemSelector()` function taken from https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter/blob/master/lib/preset-patterns.js

We use two dashes style instead of default BEM by changing the `const modifier` to match
https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#two-dashes-style

```js
/**
 * @param {String} block
 * @param {Object} [presetOptions]
 * @param {String} [presetOptions.namespace]
 * @returns {RegExp}
 */
const bemSelector = (block, presetOptions) => {
  const ns = (presetOptions && presetOptions.namespace) ? `${presetOptions.namespace}-` : '';
  const WORD = '[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*';
  const element = `(?:__${WORD})?`;
  const modifier = `(?:--${WORD}){0,2}`;
  const attribute = '(?:\\[.+\\])?';
  return new RegExp(`^\\.${ns}${block}${element}${modifier}${attribute}$`);
}

module.exports = {
  extends: 'stylelint-config-recommended-scss',
  plugins: [
    'stylelint-selector-bem-pattern'
  ],
  rules: {
    'plugin/selector-bem-pattern': {
      preset: 'bem',
      componentSelectors: bemSelector
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If anyone is reading this a few years down the line like I am, it looks like the `bemSelector()` function taken from https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter/blob/master/lib/preset-patterns.js now allows both "classic" BEM and "two-dashes" style BEM.

Here: 
https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter/blob/master/lib/preset-patterns.js#L48 

With `(?:_|--)`

Comment: I'm trying to use a SCSS selector of `&.is-open {}`as a sort of state-like class.  However I'm getting: "Stylelint: Invalid component selector ".c-stylelint.is-open" (plugin/selector-bem-pattern)"

Do you get the same? Do you have any work arounds?

Answer (score 1):

You can use stylelint's [`selector-class-pattern`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-class-pattern/) rule to enforce a pattern for class selectors using a regular expression.

However, if you're writing BEM-like CSS then [`stylelint-selector-bem-pattern`](https://github.com/davidtheclark/stylelint-selector-bem-pattern), which wraps [PostCSS BEM Linter](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter), is more powerful as it understands the concept of components, elements, modifiers and utility classes.

There is [an option](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter#define-components-and-utilities-implicitly-based-on-their-filename) to implicitly define components based on their filename, removing the need for component definitions *within* each file.